# MudBlazor : MudChipSet multiselection with filter

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I try to develop a component that is `MudChipSet` with a lot of `MudChip`. The user can select multiple chip. To help to find the desired chip, I added a filter.

The goal is to display selected chip and chip that match the filter. My try :

```cs
<MudTextField Immediate="true" @bind-Value="filter" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Adornment="Adornment.End" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" />

<MudChipSet @bind-SelectedChips="selected" MultiSelection Filter>
    @foreach (var value in Displayed)
    {
        <MudChip Text="@value"></MudChip>
    }
</MudChipSet>

<div class="d-flex flex-column align-center">
    @if (selected != null && selected.Length > 0)
    {
        <MudText>You selected @string.Join(", ", selected.Select(c => c.Text)).</MudText>
    }
    else
    {
        <MudText>Nothing selected.</MudText>
    }
</div>

@code
{
    readonly List<string> values = new List<string>() {
        "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"
    };

    string filter = string.Empty;
    MudChip[] selected = new MudChip[0];

    IEnumerable<string> Displayed => values.Where(v => v.Contains(filter) || selected.Select(c => c.Text).Contains(v));
}
```

But it don't work. When I select the element "two" and "five" (in bold **selected chip**) :

> one **two** three four **five** six seven

Then filter with "f" :

> two **four** five

Then clear the filter :

> one **two** three four five six seven

The selection is changed. It seems `MudChipSet` use the index to select chip.

---

How filter on `MudChipSet` and keep selected items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the page is rerender and it has less `MudChip`, `MudChip` can be removed in the `MudChipSet` and it is deselected.

To avoid this, all `MudChip` need to be always rendered. The solution is to render filtered `MudChip` in hidden state, like to set the style to `display: none` :

```cs
<MudTextField Immediate="true" @bind-Value="filter" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Adornment="Adornment.End" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" />

<MudChipSet @bind-SelectedChips="selected" MultiSelection Filter>
    @foreach (var value in values)
    {
        <MudChip Style="@(Displayed.Contains(value) ? string.Empty : "display: none")" Text="@value"></MudChip>
    }
</MudChipSet>

<div class="d-flex flex-column align-center">
    @if (selected != null && selected.Length > 0)
    {
        <MudText>You selected @string.Join(", ", selected.Select(c => c.Text)).</MudText>
    }
    else
    {
        <MudText>Nothing selected.</MudText>
    }
</div>

@code
{
    readonly List<string> values = new List<string>() {
        "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"
    };

    string filter = string.Empty;
    MudChip[] selected = new MudChip[0];

    IEnumerable<string> Displayed => values.Where(v => v.Contains(filter) || selected.Select(c => c.Text).Contains(v));
}
```